# O2 sensors located

Tags: dodge, o2-sensor, grand-caravan

need to know on a 2012 dodge caravan sxt v6 where are the o2 sensors located. Esp. upstream sensor 1 bank 1? Tried to look for them from above but no luck so far.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! These look to have integrated cats in the exhaust manifolds. If that's what yours looks like, it should be right at the top where the three pipes coming off the heads come together. Two of them will be closer together, with the third being separated just a little from them. The O2 should be right where that separation is at ... this should be true for either side.

Comment: Thanks Paulester2 found the right 02 sensor changed it and MPG went from 14 to 18 immediately.  Went on a small 60 mile and back(120 mile) total and got 21.5 MPG. How long will it take for the van to finish calculating the MPG?  Never had a vehicle with this feature. Probably will change all O2 sensors sometime in the future.  Haynes manual gays every 50,000 miles, van has 86,000+. Again Thank you,

Comment: Go ahead and get the other pre-cat O2 changed as soon as possible. Don't worry about the down stream O2's until they start pitching a fit. The down stream ones should have little or nothing to do with calculating the fuel trims. The upstream ones should be changed in pairs otherwise it will throw your trims out of whack. Once done, it should get you even better fuel mileage. I'm glad you are getting better fuel mileage. With a difference like that, it won't take long for them to have paid you back, especially with the raise in fuel prices here recently.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps:

[image]

I think I have circled Bank 1, but I'm not entirely sure.  The other upstream O2 sensor is not visible in this picture, but it's a mirror image and located in the same region.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe on a V6 or V8 for that matter Bank 1 is usually the left hand side when facing the engine from the front of the vehicle. Locate the exhaust manifold and follow the exhaust pipes until you find the catalytic convertor. The upstream O2 sensor the sensor at the beginning of the cat. That tells the ECM your air fuel ratio. The downstream O2 sensor is that is on the end of the cat. It doesn't do a helluva of a lot until it detects O2 from the cat at that point the cat is finished  and you get a check engine light.